# apache ignite is not creating cache back up properly on all nodes

Tags: java, caching, ignite

I am new to this field so do not have much knowledge about this.
I am just trying a simple program to print cache value (in partitioned mode and 1 back up).

App Details:- (both are running different jvm) - all of them are using same config xml file

1. Program A will create cache A and print cache B
2. Program B will create cache B and print cache A

steps: -

1. started program A first with are create the cahe A from this progrm(commented that section) - Node 1
2. Again started program A ( Node 2)on different jvm. so now program  A is running on two nodes and printing Cache B = null
3. started proram B (Node 3) and it created the cache B and printing cache A=null and othe other hand progm A is now pring cache B = Some value on both the node 1/2.
4. now ran A again and created the cache A [Node 4] (uncommenting that section) and on Node 3 cache B = Somevalue now. All looks goos till this point

   so ideally ignite should create a back up of cache A on any of the running node.
5. Now I stopped Node 4 (program A with cache creation), but on Node 3 value of cache A became null.
6. then I stopped program B on Node 3 and value of cache B beacame null on Node 1 & 2.

could you please let me know if somewhere I am wrong ? why Ignite it not creating the Back up copy of cache A/B on the other nodes ?

Comment: Could you attach your Ignite config?  
What exactly does the check "Cache A = null"?  
Actually, if I understand the steps correctly, cache B should have been able to observe values from cache A at step 3.  
As well, please note that there is no need to create a cache multiple times - nodes joining a cluster will detect that the cache already exists.

Comment: @alexfedotov I am using the same config xml on this example (https://github.com/apache/ignite/tree/master/examples) only thing I added is cacheMode = PARTITIONED and Backup value = 1. in my case, cache A will be created on step 4 and cache B on step 3. Step 1,2 will not create the cache as I commected them.

Comment: What about the way you check "Cache A = null" or "Cache A = Somevalue"?  
Do you read values put into the cache? Could you share the code fragment of this check?